# How to start after installing OpenStack

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cloud, hadoop, openstack

I have installed `OpenStack` following the tutorial from [here](http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/setting-up-a-single-node-openstack-environment/) I want to know that how can I deploy simple PHP application using `Apache Hadoop` on OpenStack?

Any reference?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [this](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Sahara) page for more details on how to setup hadoop on Openstack.

Answer (score 0):

If you have everything set up for deploying virtual machines, you can have a look at provisioning tools to further automate deployments for your machines.

I would recommend [Chef](https://docs.chef.io/provisioning.html) or [Packer](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/provisioners.html).

Especially with Chef, you can try the openly available recipes for Apache Hadoop like [this](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/hadoop) or [that](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/apache_hadoop).

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit to better describe the "how"? Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.